# ODP.NET: Error when load data from Timesten refCursor to DataTable

Tags: oracle, odp.net, timesten

I want to load data from Timesten DB to datatable, but i get error
Here is my code

Script:

```
create or replace FUNCTION APITT_tbl_request(prefix_db IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN res FOR SELECT * FROM APITT_tbl_request_in;
    RETURN res;
END;
```

C# code

```
conn = new OracleConnection(conf.GetAPIDatabaseConnectionString());
conn.Open();
OracleTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
command = new OracleCommand(@"BEGIN :RETURNCURSOR := APITT_tbl_request(:prefix_db); END;");
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("RETURNCURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
command.Parameters.Add("prefix_db", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = prefix_db;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Error in da.Fill(dt);

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the connection that the command uses.

With ODP.NET it's possible to have more than one connection open at the same time.  If you don't specify which connection a command should use, how is ODP.NET supposed to know?

Either add the line

```
command.Connection = conn;
```

or replace the line

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
```

with

```
OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
```